# jQuery Append Nesting

Tags: jquery, append

```
var f = a('<span class="customSelectInnerText" />');
var e = a('<span class="customSelect"><span class="customSelectInner"></span></span>').append(f);
```

results in:

```
<span class="customSelect>
   <span class="customSelectInner"></span>
   <span class="customSelectInnerText">Text</span>
</span>
```

instead of the desired:

```
<span class="customSelect>
   <span class="customSelectInner">
      <span class="customSelectInnerText">Text</span>
   </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement selects the outer most element. You have to select the inner child before appending the previous `<span>`. Change to:

```
var e = a('<span class="customSelect"><span class="customSelectInner"></span></span>')
            .children().append(f);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want just to adjust your code, you need to append `f` to `.`customSelectInner, it can be done with `find`.

```
var f = a('<span class="customSelectInnerText" />');
var e = a('<span class="customSelect">' +
          '<span class="customSelectInner"></span></span>')
         .find('.customSelectInner')append(f);
```

Note that I would break that code so every element has it's own variable, it's a lot more readable and easier to maintain and debug.

Answer (score 1):

```
var f = a('<span class="customSelectInnerText" />');

var e = a('<span class="customSelect"><span class="customSelectInner"></span></span>');
$(".customSelectInner").append(f);
```